# Applying putStr to each item of a list

Tags: list, haskell, printing

I'm trying to print out a list of integers in this format

```
[1]
[2]
[3]
```

So my function takes a list of integers and returns an IO () like so:

```
import System.IO

printVector :: [Integer] -> IO ()
printVector (x:xs) = putStr("[" ++ show(x) ++ "]" ++ "\n") : printVector xs
```

But ghc gives me the error:

```
lin-test.hs:5:22:
Couldn't match expected type `IO ()' with actual type `[a0]'
In the expression:
  putStr ("[" ++ show (x) ++ "]" ++ "") : printVector xs
In an equation for `printVector':
    printVector (x : xs)
      = putStr ("[" ++ show (x) ++ "]" ++ "") : printVector xs
Failed, modules loaded: none.
```

Now it is my understanding that the function would run through the list, taking the first item 'x' first, and then with : printVector xs it would recursively call the rest of the list applying the same putStr function to each item in the list.

But I think my problem is where I do : printVector xs?
Can anyone point out what i'm doing wrong here?

Comment: Simplest change: `>> printVector xs` instead of `: printVector xs`.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You need to map over the list but, as these are IO actions, you also need to execute them (as `map` will return a list of IO action without executing them, see following example).

```
sequence $ map (putStrLn . show) [1,2,3,4]
```

There is a function doing that already, it's `mapM`. So the example can be simplify as :

```
mapM (putStrLn . show) [1,2,3,4]
```

Another thing you can do is using `mapM_` which uses `sequence_` instead and will ignore the result of executing the IO action to each of the elements. Therefore, the return type will be `IO ()` instead of `IO [()]` (previous example).

```
mapM_ (putStrLn . show) [1,2,3,4]
```

Comment: I see. This is a very useful function. Is there a way for me to add to this, say I want to do the formatting myself like I wrote above, mapM_ ("[" ++ putStr ++ "]" ++ "\n" . show) [1,2,3,4]. This is of course wrong but I would really like to be able to print them out like this

Comment: @enkitosh: Split the IO and formatting: `mapM_ (putStr . format) [1..4]` and `format x = "[" ++ show x ++ "]\n"`.

Comment: @enkitosh Use a lambda, `mapM_ (\n -> putStrLn $ "[" ++ show n ++ "]") [1,2,3,4]`, or, IMO more readable, `import Control.Monad (forM_)` and `forM_ [1,2,3,4] $ \n -> putStrLn $ "[" ++ show n ++ "]"`. (`forM_ = flip mapM_`)

Comment: That's amazing. Thanks. Both of your answers were very helpful!